# About the automatic promotion of js block-level scope functions

Tags: javascript, scope

Why the first one is ReferenceError,And the second one is TypeError?

[image: ReferenceError]

Answer (score 0):

**First One:**
The function z is not declared that's why you got ReferrenceError.

**Second One:**
The function z is declared, but inside the If/Else statement. So the scope of the function z is limited only inside the If/Else block. Hence you got the TypeError.

*How to make it work?*

Call the function z inside the If/Else block like below, it would work without error.

```
var a = true;
if(a) {
    z();
    function z() {console.log("a");}
}else{
    z();
    function z() {console.log("b");}
}
```

**Recommendation:**
Use If/Else inside a function, not the other way. See below example:

```
z();

function z() {
    var a = true;
    if(a) {     
        console.log("a");
    }else{
        console.log("b");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the language feature referred to as [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).

In the first example, the function `z()` is literally never defined - therefore you get a reference error just like this code produces:

```js
b(); // undefined - produces ReferenceError since 'b' cannot be found
```

In the second example the function declaration for `z()` is *hoisted* within its enclosing scope - which is the code block. This is demonstrated here:

```js
{
  a();
  function a() {
    console.log('this is a');
  }
}
```

Finally, the result you are seeing is browser dependent. In Chrome, the variable `c` will be `undefined` in the outer scope, but will produce a TypeError because the identifier `c` has been established. In Safari, `c` is defined as a function and executes as expected. So in this case, Safari has *hoisted* the declaration of `c()` to the outer scope while Chrome does not.

```js
console.log(c);
c();
{
   console.log(typeof c);
   function c(){ console.log('this is c');}
}
```